# jQuery Regex Replace String in Textarea on Key Up

Tags: jquery, regex

I think I'm really close. How can I get the "newtitle" variable to match what is typed in the Title field?

See exactly: https://jsfiddle.net/a0cj8xmy

jQuery:

```
var newtitle = 'This works but isn\'t what I type';
//var newtitle = $('$title-field').text(); // This doesn't work
//var newtitle = $('$title-field').html(); // This doesn't work
//var newtitle = $('$title-field').val(); // This doesn't work

$('#title-field').bind('keyup', function(){
  $('#body-field').html($('#body-field').html().replace(/title=""/g,'title="'+newtitle+'"')); 
});
```

HTML:

```
Title:<br>
<input type="text" id="title-field" placeholder="Type here!">

Body:<br>
<textarea id="body-field" name="body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="10">
<a href="" title=""><img src="" class="" /></a>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Replace `$title-field` by `#title-field`

Comment: Good eye, but var newtitle = $('#title-field').val(); still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have to know that `.val()` returns a string, which is copied (and not a reference). You will need to fetch the new title in the listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments we had on @ArunKumar's answer, I refactored the whole code. Also I stripped the jQuery parts :

```
const titleField = document.getElementById('title-field'),
  bodyField = document.getElementById('body-field');

titleField.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  bodyField.value = bodyField.value.replace(/title=".*?"/g, `title="${titleField.value}"`);
})
```

First I save the 2 HTML elements for easier use. Then, I add the event listener, and inside the listener, I change the value of the `textArea` element by replacing the relevent part.

Now you can edit the textArea inner text as you want, and you will still be able to change the title attribute (or all `title` attributes, as the RegExp has the `global` tag).

Edit : as from your last comment, you can add the `readonly` attribute on the textArea HTML element so that it cannot be manually modified.

Comment: this is excellent! Thank you for helping develop both answers-- I appreciate your time on this! Thanks also to Arun Kumar for helping pave the way.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using id selector `#` to get value and get value inside keyup function not outside or just not use any var for this use direct value

Also the Regular Expression will only match if the title is empty, so it has been changed to match all characters between the quotes.

```
var areaVal=$('#body-field').val();
$('#title-field').keyup(function(){
  if($('#body-field').val().indexOf("<a")==-1)
     $('#body-field').val(areaVal);
   $('#body-field').val($('#body-field').val().replace(/title=".*?"/g,'title="'+$(this).val()+'"'));
 });
```

Comment: Good eye on the $ vs #, but this doesn't seem to work... any idea?

Comment: updated my answer. You need to get value inside keyup function

Comment: You could keep the `newTitle` variable scoped to the listener and define it inside.

Comment: I think there is no need to use var

Comment: Indeed. Nice use of the `this` context, by the way :)

Comment: It seems to only enter the first character. Check the fiddle.

Comment: @WebMW That issue is from the regex. Change `/title=""/g` to `/title=".*?"/g`

Comment: @Seblor that works great! Until I change the changed value in the textarea, which functionality seems to break. Any way to avoid that too? (or possibly a way to sync one another?)

Comment: @WebMW This is caused by the behavior of the textArea element. It's value is "linked" with the inner HTML. I do not know how to fix that easily without heavily refactoring your code.

Comment: @Seblor Syncing may be out of the scope, but it's unfortunately a problem that any changes made to the textarea render this script obsolete.

Comment: If you want to have anchor tag for each change then you can store the HTML of the textarea on each update from text box and then append it again

Comment: @ArunKumar could you possibly demonstrate? Here is the updated fiddle showing it working "IF" any changes haven't already been made to the text box: https://jsfiddle.net/a0cj8xmy/72/

Comment: @WebMW I fail to understand why would you edit the textarea. What is your goal, actually ?

Comment: @Seblor this is for old 70 year olds to use, where everything and anything can happen. It clearly eases the process of inserting image captions. Would be great if this script could work if in the event 1) Content is being modified 2) They happen to write some body text before inserting a title.

Comment: @ArunKumar This works excellent as well! I really wish I could select two best answers. I actually prefer the jQuery way even if it requires a tiny bit more code. Thank you for all of your help! I will probably be using this :)

Comment: glad to know that :)